# VS2010: Have to constantly copy over my PDB files every time I rebuild

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2010, iis-6, remote-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.  I work with mostly windows services and web services.  I use IIS6 w/web sites pointed at my project's bin/debug build, Windows 7, C#...not sure what other info will be relevant...anyway..the problem is that in order to debug I have to copy over PDB files to the temp asp.net dirs

Every time I rebuild my project (which is huge), I have to drill down into the windows/ms.net/framework/v4/temp/root/[random] directory...wherein I must open up each of the 50-some randomly named directories in there that hold the built dll's, and I must copy the PDB files from my project's /bin/debug directory to each respective dll folder.  Needless to say this is causing me to grow old faster than I should be.

If I don't do this, then when I attach to remote process for debugging and set a breakpoint...I get a circle instead of a dot for a breakpoint and it says something about symbols not loaded.

My co-worker says this is a visual studio x64 bug but I think it's a build configuration done wrong.  Any ideas?  Lemme know if you need more information, I'm not sure what's wrong so I apologize if the explanation is a little wonky, thanks

Comment: To be clear, you're running VS 2010 on a 64bit Windows XP install?

Comment: VS2010 on 64bit Win 7 install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not compiling the project in "Release Mode.